# CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1::/restapis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

Can someone please assist in pointing out what the issue might be when I try to access AWS apigateway resources using AWS Amplify Javascript SDK.

When a user logs into the platform (a portal I'm building)- the role assumed by the AuthRole is able to load the API catalogue as per the permissions to allow read access for all apigateway resources. Here is how the policy looks like:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "appsync:*",
                "apigateway:GET",
                "apigateway:POST",
                "apigateway:DELETE",
                "apigateway:PATCH",
                "apigateway:PUT",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateStackSet",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStackSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResource",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackSetOperation",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStackSet",
                "cloudfront:CreateCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
                "cloudfront:CreateDistribution",
                "cloudfront:DeleteCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
                "cloudfront:DeleteDistribution",
                "cloudfront:GetCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
                "cloudfront:GetCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig",
                "cloudfront:GetDistribution",
                "cloudfront:GetDistributionConfig",
                "cloudfront:TagResource",
                "cloudfront:UntagResource",
                "cloudfront:UpdateCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
                "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution",
                "cognito-identity:CreateIdentityPool",
                "cognito-identity:DeleteIdentityPool",
                "cognito-identity:DescribeIdentity",
                "cognito-identity:DescribeIdentityPool",
                "cognito-identity:SetIdentityPoolRoles",
                "cognito-identity:UpdateIdentityPool",
                "cognito-idp:CreateUserPool",
                "cognito-idp:CreateUserPoolClient",
                "cognito-idp:DeleteUserPool",
                "cognito-idp:DeleteUserPoolClient",
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPool",
                "cognito-idp:UpdateUserPool",
                "cognito-idp:UpdateUserPoolClient",
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteTable",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateTable",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:UpdateRole",
                "lambda:AddPermission",
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:DeleteFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:RemovePermission",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration",
                "s3:*",
                "amplify:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above policy is associated with the authRole (role when user is authenticated) and is working as expected along with the below code:

```
public async configureAwsIdentityCredentials(): Promise<boolean> {
    const sessionUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();

    const idToken = sessionUser.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;
    const cognitoParams = {IdentityPoolId: environment.appClient.identityPoolId, Logins: {}};

    cognitoParams.Logins[environment.cognitoIdpUrl + environment.appClient.userPoolId] = idToken;
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(cognitoParams);

    return of(true).toPromise();

  }
```

The issue comes in when I need to pull the resources from AWS without an unauthenticated user- I have enabled unauthenticated access on the Identity Pool and attached the above policy to the unauthRole. I am receiving an instance of AWS.ICredentials when running the below code... although when I run the application, I receive an access denied error... below is the snippet for unauthenticated access:

```
public async configureCurrentCreditialsWithoutLogin(): Promise<boolean> {
    const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();

    AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

    return of(true).toPromise();

  }
```

[image: Error on console]

Herewith the textContent for the console error on the image:

ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXX:assumed-role/amplify-XXXX-unauthRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1::/restapis

Please see the below error events from Cloudtrail (Auth and unauth):
Auth:

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "AROAUKJTJFOLBWD5XZVSP:CognitoIdentityCredentials",
        "arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/xxx-authRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials",
        "accountId": "xxx",
        "accessKeyId": "xxx",
        "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": "AROAUKJTJFOLBWD5XZVSP",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx-authRole",
                "accountId": "xxx",
                "userName": "xxx-authRole"
            },
            "webIdFederationData": {
                "federatedProvider": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com",
                "attributes": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "[\"authenticated\",\"cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_cCdLTN7nA\",\"cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_cCdLTN7nA:CognitoSignIn:6c6f8c2e-d7e9-4e31-99dd-0c46898fd9a2\"]",
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-west-1:2a0fcef4-dd19-4db5-955f-5e1a2865f821",
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": "eu-west-1:d5a7dc54-67f9-4b9e-9993-91e2cfa9d624"
                }
            },
            "attributes": {
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false",
                "creationDate": "2020-06-10T14:58:43Z"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2020-06-10T14:58:44Z",
    "eventSource": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "GetRestApis",
    "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "41.113.113.159",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0",
    "requestParameters": {
        "limit": 20,
        "template": false
    },
    "responseElements": null,
    "requestID": "db448c52-dd00-4c51-af23-e3e51c934407",
    "eventID": "b6aa7c4b-120e-49a8-b81c-2256f7ee4491",
    "readOnly": true,
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": "xxx"
}
```

Unauth:

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "AROAUKJTJFOLPFSCSBJPE:CognitoIdentityCredentials",
        "arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/xxx-unauthRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials",
        "accountId": "xxx",
        "accessKeyId": "xxx",
        "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": "AROAUKJTJFOLPFSCSBJPE",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx-unauthRole",
                "accountId": "xxx",
                "userName": "xxx-unauthRole"
            },
            "webIdFederationData": {
                "federatedProvider": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com",
                "attributes": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "[\"unauthenticated\"]",
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-west-1:2a0fcef4-dd19-4db5-955f-5e1a2865f821",
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": "eu-west-1:05fe8797-163f-4cee-98c1-754ad268d83b"
                }
            },
            "attributes": {
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false",
                "creationDate": "2020-06-10T14:58:00Z"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2020-06-10T14:58:01Z",
    "eventSource": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "GetRestApis",
    "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "169.0.135.161",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0",
    "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
    "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/xxx-unauthRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: apigateway:GET on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1::/restapis",
    "requestParameters": null,
    "responseElements": null,
    "requestID": "e9091a88-dc61-4999-8683-336fbf4fbc74",
    "eventID": "977ca45c-559e-4a31-9960-41accfb1aaa7",
    "readOnly": true,
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": "xxx"
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to copy the error message as text, not a tiny screenshot?

Comment: Hi Marcin- I have updated the query...

Comment: Do you have CloudTrail logging enabled? If so, do you see a matching error in the CloudTrail logs? Could you post a redacted set of logs showing the unauth role failing, and another set that show the auth role succeeding? (I'm hoping that by seeing the CloudTrail logs surrounding the success / failure it will be possible to identify where the paths are diverging).

Comment: Hi Alex- I will check if I have Cloudtrail logging enabled and try and get the logs for both scenarios... thanks

Comment: Hi Alex- I have added the events from Cloudtrail.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. An unauth federated identify is not able to perform GET on restapi, while it added in the IAM. How did you solve this?